# Locking paragraphs together with CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've checked the CKEditor documentation but cannot find an option to 'lock' paragraphs of text together to stop them becoming separated between page breaks. In MS Word, it's called 'keep with next'. E.g.

[image: Keep together - MS Word]

CKEditor seems pretty feature rich so I wonder if I can't find it because of a terminology problem, or if it's some custom function I need to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, as it only contains what is needed, but not the final solution.
But hopefully it will help for further searching.

CKEditor can only do things that are provided by CSS itself.

What you are looking for is to set the [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/) style property to `avoid`.

That can be solved in different ways:

- Having a class like `keep-with-next` and define a rule for that class with `page-break-after: avoid`, and setting that class for the element using CKEditor.
- Having a plugin that sets `page-break-after: avoid` as inline style.